# Consecutive run programming

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to show the sentence "Hello" that is after finish process of `main` method:

1. input name and it's correct,
2. ask age, and
3. correct going to sentence "booting up"

which means I want to run method consecutively.

I only could run main method and not to be able to show the sentence "Hello".

How could I fix this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is call the hello method at the end of your main method. Also you are missing a `}` after `System.out.println("Hello");`

Something like this:

```
public class YourClassName {
    public static void main (String [] theArgs){
        //your code here ....
        hello();
    }
    public static void Hello(){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes!This is what I wanted to do.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure,Thank you for your support.